# Using Airflow macro outside of operators

Tags: hadoop, macros, airflow

Is there any way to use Airflow macro outside of any operators?

For example, in the DAG I have an action:

```
datestamp = '{{ ds }}'

print(datestamp) # prints string not the date when I run it for any date

scanner = S3KeySensor(
        task_id='scanner',
        poke_interval=60,
        timeout=24 * 60 * 60,
        soft_fail=False,
        wildcard_match=True,
        bucket_key=getPath() + datestamp, #datestamp correctly replaced with execution date
        bucket_name=bucketName,
        dag=dag)
```

So when calling scanner, "ds" value gets replaced with execution date which is expected, but I want to use "ds" value in some other places. But in that case, it doesn't replace value, instead it gets entire string as "{{ ds }}". In the above example. print statement prints "{{ ds }}" not the execution date.

Answer (score 3):

Lucky for you `bucket_key` is templated, just put the jinja template inside.

```
…
bucket_key=getPath() + '{{ ds }}',
…
```

Completely outside an operator you cannot use these macros. Because the file is interpreted regularly by the scheduler, and not just during a dag run. So what would the value of `ds` be when the dag isn't running?

However since you're unlikely to want to do anything with it outside the tasks, you could put it into a templated field. You can also extend another field to be templated.

```
class MySensor(S3KeySensor):
    template_fields = ('bucket_key', 'bucket_name', 'my_thing')

    def __init__(self, my_thing=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.my_thing = my_thing

    def post_execute(self, context):
        logging.info(
           "I probably wanted to over-ride poke to use {}".format(self.my_thing)

scanner = MySensor(
    my_thing='{{ ds }}',
    task_id='scanner',
    poke_interval=60,
    timeout=24 * 60 * 60,
    soft_fail=False,
    wildcard_match=True,
    bucket_key=getPath() + '{{ ds }}',
    bucket_name=bucketName,
    dag=dag)
```

Edit: IIRC `self.my_thing` doesn't change after the init, rather, the `context.my_thing` will get templated just before (?`pre_execute` and) `execute` is called.

Comment: Does that mean the macro is substituted in the `init` and anywhere else if I refer to `self.my_thing` it should refer to a substituted string? For me, if I refer to `self.my_thing` in some other function within the `MySensor`, the macro is not substituted.

Answer (score -5):

Use double quotes.

```
datestamp = "{{ ds }}"
print datestamp
```